# Load Balancing in Cluster ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-artemis

Let's say that I have 3 ActiveMQ Artemis brokers in one cluster:

1. Broker_01
2. Broker_02
3. Broker_03

In a given point of time I have a number of consumers for each broker:

1. Broker_01 has 50 consumers
2. Broker_02 has 10 consumers
3. Broker_03 has 10 consumers

Let's assume at this given point of time there are 70 messages to be sent to a queue in this cluster.

We are expecting load balancing done by the cluster so that Broker_01 would receive 50 messages, Broker_02 10 messages, and Broker_03 also 10 messages, but currently we are experiencing that the 70 messages are distributed randomly through all the 3 brokers.

Is there any configuration I can do to distribute the messages based on the number of consumers in each broker?

I just read [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html).  So, as far as I understood, ActiveMQ does load balancing, based on round robin, if we configure cluster connection.  Our broker.xml looks like this:

```xml
        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                <connector-ref>amq-v01_connector</connector-ref>
                <min-large-message-size>524288</min-large-message-size>
                <call-timeout>120000</call-timeout>
                <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
                <retry-interval-multiplier>1.5</retry-interval-multiplier>
                <max-retry-interval>2000</max-retry-interval>
                <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <notification-interval>800</notification-interval>
                <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
                <static-connectors>
                    <connector-ref>amq-v02_connector</connector-ref>
                </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
```

Further, address-setting for the queue looks like this:

```xml
            <address-setting match="MyQueue">
                <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                <max-size-bytes>50Mb</max-size-bytes>
            </address-setting>
```

Am I missing something, so that load balancing will be done?

The next point would be as stated in documentation, load balancing is always done based on round robin, there is no configuration possible to load balance based on number of consumers in each node.

I assume that I need client-side connection load-balancing since we want to load-balance the messages arriving in the 3 brokers according to the number of consumers in each broker. As stated in the documentation, there are 5 out-of-the-box policies (Round-Robin, First Element, etc.) which we can use. Additionally we could implement our own policy by implementing `ConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy`. Assuming that I would like to implement my own policy, what would be the idea how to do this according the number of consumer?

Comment: to be honest, after reading the documentation, i am still not sure, but i assume that it is the client-side connection load-balancing, since we want to load-balance the messages, arriving in the 3 brokers according to the number of consumers in each broker.  As stated in the documentation, there are 5 out-of-the-box policies(Round-Robin, ..., First Element) we can use.  Additionally we could implement our own policy by implementing ConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy.  Assuming that I would like to implement my own policy, what would be the idea how to do this according the number of consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way for the producer to know how many consumers are on each broker and then send messages to those messages to those brokers accordingly.

It is possible for you to implement your own `ConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy`. However, in order to determine how many consumers exist on the queue load-balancing policy implementation would need to know the URL of all the brokers in the cluster as well as name of the queue to which you're sending messages, and there's no way to supply that information. The `ConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy` interface is *very* simple.

I would encourage you to revisit your need for a 3-node cluster in the first place if each node is going to have *so few* messages on it. A single broker can handle a throughput of millions of messages in certain use-cases. If each node is dealing with less than 50 messages then you probably don't need a cluster at all.